# What do I need in order to fix the sloppy work done by cable providers?

Tags: electrical, low-voltage, coaxial-cable

As some of you have surely experienced, residential telecom installers can leave a thing or two to be desired when it comes to how they get the service into our homes.

A small project I've had in mind is to repair the extra holes in my home, and to do a better cable management job with all this coax. **What do I need to repair the walls and organize this mess?**

*Note: I use separate providers for internet and TV*

[image: Incoming]
Incoming coax

[image: Exterior]
Exterior coax

[image: cable management]
"Cable management"

Comment: Organize is a vague term.  Be more specific please.  Are these holes in publicly visible spaces?

Comment: Regarding organization, this is in a closet. I only want to fix it because I like fixing things.

Comment: This question might be useful [How do I properly feed coax through an outside wall?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/42192/33).  [This answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/38072/33)  is also helpful.  They make modular wall plates with a variety of holes, that can accept a variety of ports. You'll need a 4 port plate for the first photo, and a six port plate for the other.  Then you'll need modular F type connectors to plug into the plates.

Comment: When you're putting ends on CATV cables, I recommend the crimp type ends. Yes they require a special crimp tool, but they are just way better than the twist-on type.

Comment: [This answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/38100/33) might be helpful if you're putting new ends on the cables.

Comment: A [Demarcation Enclosure](https://www.aflglobal.com/Products/Copper-Apparatus/Demarcation/Coax-Demarcation/CableGuard-500-Coax-Demarcation-Enclosure.aspx) can be used to hide the connections outside.